# Example code for Scrapy process_links and process_request

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and I was hoping if anyone can give me good example codes of when process_links and process_request are most useful. I see that process_links is used to filter URL's but I don't know how to code it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You mean `scrapy.spiders.Rule` that is most commonly used in `scrapy.CrawlSpider`

They do pretty much what the names say or in other words that act as sort of middleware between the time the link is extracted and processed/downloaded.

`process_links` sits between when link is extracted and turned into request . There are pretty cool use cases for this, just to name a few common ones:

1. Filter out some links you don't like.
2. Do redirection manually to avoid bad requests.

example:

```
def process_links(self, link):
    for link in links:
        #1
        if 'foo' in link.text:
            continue  # skip all links that have "foo" in their text
        yield link 
        #2
        link.url = link.url + '/'  # fix url to avoid unnecessary redirection
        yield link
```

`process_requests` sits between request that was just made and before it is being downloaded. It shares some use cases with the `process_links` but can actually do some other cool stuff like:

1. Modify headers(e.g. cookies).
2. Change details like callback, depending on some keywords in the url.

example:

```
def process_req(self, req):
    # 1
    req = req.replace(headers={'Cookie':'foobar'})
    return req
    # 2
    if 'foo' in req.url:
        return req.replace(callback=self.parse_foo)
    elif 'bar' in req.url:
        return req.replace(callback=self.parse_bar)
    return req
```

You probably not gonna use them often but these two can be really convenient and easy shortcuts on some occasions.

Comment: Cool! This is great. Thank you. This solves a problem I was having. I have 2 questions though 1) In your process_links code, isn't the last 2 lines redundant because you have a return link before it?   2) If I return a None in process_links, I get a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". I know I can ignore this error because Scrapy moves to the next link anyways, but can I fix this error in any way? I was hoping that Scrapy would move on if it sees a NoneType returned.

Comment: Regarding #1 - I've just used it to show off two examples to save space. Regarding #2 - there's a bit of a typo on my end, the `process_links` function actually takes in a list of links and expects some list as return, I've adjusted my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Granitosaurus This is really helpful - thanks. I believe your `process_links()` function might confuse future readers with its `return None` statement. Any chance you can replace it with `continue` to skip bad links or something similar to make it more accurate?

Comment: I guess you should pass the list so links instead of link. However I can't get it to work. I am calling the method with Rule(..., process_links='process_links') and using def process_links(self, links):