# Scrapy Rules: Exclude certain urls with process links

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am very happy to having discovered the Scrapy Crawl Class with its Rule Objects. However when I am trying to extract urls which contain the word "login" with process_links it doesn't work. The solution I implemented comes from here: [Example code for Scrapy process_links and process_request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400489/example-code-for-scrapy-process-links-and-process-request) but it doesn't exclude the pages I want

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from accenture.items import AccentureItem

class AccentureSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'accenture_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.accenture.com/us-en/internet-of-things-index']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[contains(@href, "insight")]'), callback='parse_item',process_links='process_links', follow=True),
    ) 

    def process_links(self, links):
        for link in links:
            if 'login' in link.text:
                continue  # skip all links that have "login" in their text
            yield link 

    def parse_item(self, response):
        loader = ItemLoader(item=AccentureItem(), response=response)
        url = response.url
        loader.add_value('url', url)
        yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you checked what is the value of `link.text` for those cases that are unexpectedly not filtered out?

Comment: yes I solved the problem thank you! I had to use link.url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was to use link.text
When using link.url it works fine :)