# Why is process_links not returning any links to the Rule()?

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to understand the "process_links" callback option of the Rule within Scrapy.

This post here helped already, but didn't completely solved my problem:
[Example code for Scrapy process_links and process_request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400489/example-code-for-scrapy-process-links-and-process-request)

My goal: I need to remove everything after the ? in the URL:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='... CSS CODE ...'), process_links='delete_random_garbage_from_url', callback='parse_item', follow=True),

def delete_random_garbage_from_url(self, urls):
     for url in urls:
         print(url.url.split('?')[0])
         url.url = url.url.split('?')[0]
```

the print is working correctly, so I get printed all urls without parameters.
But the second line in the for loop throws this error:

returns: **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the spider is working fine? The callable given to `process_links` is passed a list of `Link` objects, and so `split` shouldn't work on them...

Comment: You have been right. Crawler didn't work properly. Now it does and I get an error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. yield link was missing.
So if anyone is looking for a way to filter a URL before passing it on, here you go:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='WHAT ARE YOU LOOKING FOR'), process_links='delete_random_garbage_from_url', callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    
def delete_random_garbage_from_url(self, links):
    for link in links:
        link.url = link.url.split('?')[0] #do what you need to do, here remove everything from URL after the ?
        yield link
```

Thanks for your help @tomjn